# Multiple checkbox in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, checkbox

How do I make a multiple checkbox in the react native `<CheckBox></CheckBox>`?

Currently my checkbox is like this :

```
if(this.state.specialise_list != null){
  return this.state.specialise_list.map((data, i)=>(
    <View key={i} style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <CheckBox
        containerStyle={{ borderColor: 'transparent' }}
        value={this.state.specialise}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemKey) => this.setState({ specialise: itemValue })} />
      <Text style={{marginTop: 5}}> { data.name }</Text>
    </View>
  ))
}
```

My above code will check all the checkbox. I'm trying to insert the checked checkbox in an array in this form `selected_specialise: [ '1', '2', '5', '24' ];` where the data will be removed from the array if the specific checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check then if the `selected_specialise` array contains the index.

```
if(this.state.specialise_list != null){
  return this.state.specialise_list.map((data, i)=>(
    <View key={i} style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <CheckBox
        containerStyle={{ borderColor: 'transparent' }}
        value={this.state.selected_specialise.includes(i)}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemKey) => this.setState({ specialise: itemValue })} />
      <Text style={{marginTop: 5}}> { data.name }</Text>
    </View>
  ))
}
```

If you meant 1 as the first then `..includes(i + 1)`